# What's Spanish for "manlet"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, insultos

Yesterday I came across a slang word I didn't know and I'm curious to know if there is a proper translation in Spanish. It seems that in English there is the derogatory term `manlet`. After seeing it in a comment I googled it and I couldn't find much beyond [UrbanDictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Manlet), [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/manlet#:%7E:text=Noun,man%2C%20especially%20a%20muscular%20one.), reddit and the like. Since it is a slang word, this term does not appear in any official. dictionary

It seems that a *manlet* (again, used as a derogatory term) is a short but very muscular man. Some of the definitions convey that the man might be trying to overcompensate for his short height with his musculature.

In Spanish there are several slang words for very muscular men (cachas, *mazao*, mazas, etc.)

Is there a Spanish word (derogatory or not) that could be used to convey what manlet does? A "cachas" or "mazao" that has short height (and might be trying to (over)compensate his short height with his musculature)?

Answer (score 6):

In Argentina, we might use the term "poroto inflado" (inflated bean) to refer to somebody short or small who works out to look bigger.

This expression, however, can also be found when making reference to somebody unimportant who experiences an unexpected rise to fame and then brags about his newly acquired reputation or wealth.

The term is really pejorative and sounds funny because it is clearly descriptive of something intrinsically small that has become artificially bigger.